# Is it possible to restrict the visibility of domains in CSP frame-ancestors?

Tags: iframe, content-security-policy

We have an iframe that is currently deployed on customer websites.  We use the CSP frame-ancestors directive to limit how and where the iframes can be deployed.  For example:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' some-customer.com another-customer.com;
```

Unfortunately `some-customer.com` and `another-customer.com` is leaked, in terms of revealing that our those customers are deploying our service.

Is there a way to prevent this while preserving iframe security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if your CSP is customized for every pageload. If the Referrer header in the request is on the list of approved hosts you add it to frame-ancestors.

This is basically the same mechanism that should be used for Access-Control-Allow-Origin, especially when sharing credentials.